# how to access the value of edittext inside fragment which is in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am having am mainActivity which consists of 3 fragment activity in a view pager .each fragment consists of edit texts .How to get the value of the edit text when swipe fragment horizontally ? I am trying to do like this.below code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

int value = 0;
Context context;
String a = "";

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    //final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mAddButtonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnewB);

    mAddSearchV = findViewById(R.id.addnewSearch);
    mAddButtonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAddSearchV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        }
    });
        }



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    PageZero p0;
    PageOne p1;
    PageTwo p2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        p0 = new PageZero();
        p1 = new PageOne();
        p2 = new PageTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        switch (position) {
        case 0:
             return p0;
        case 1:
            return p1;
        case 2:
            return p2;
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }


}
// PageZero = (Fragment1)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1");
public class PageZero extends Fragment {
 private  EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentname, container,
                false);
        name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

        name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                a=name.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });/*(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                a=name.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });*/
        return view;
    }
}

public class PageOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentaddress, container,
                false);


        return view;
    }
}

public class PageTwo extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentmobno, container,
                false);
        return view;
    }
}


}
```

when i try to access the eddittext inside pageZero class like below

```
 name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
 a=name.getText().toString().trim();
```

i am getting null value.help me out..Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chnmaya can you get any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Change the pagezero class oncreateview code like this .....

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.componentname,null);
        name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

        name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                a=name.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

 return view;
        });
```

Return the view friend and then use default layout inflater...

Comment: Perfect, I looked almost everywhere to get this solution. Thanks you saved my day, Thanks #Android Developer

Comment: If I may ask, how would changing `inflater` to `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` help in this case? As far as I'm aware, this is exactly the same. Also, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

At the time you click the edittext field, is there any content? Maybe you should get the text in the lost focus event of the edittext field. Thus you can enter some text first...

**Example:**

```
name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus == false){
                //get text from edittext field...
            }

        }
    });
```

The way you try to get the text looks right to me. At least I do it the same way.

In the PagerAdapter's 'getItem' Method you should instantiate your fragments directly:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new PageZero();
        case 1:
            return new PageOne();
        case 2:
            return new PageTwo();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Viewpager only calls getItem if it wants to create a new item. Unfortunatly they called the method getItem and not createItem which would be more obvious.

Comment: can u tell where should i access the edittext to get the value entered.?

Comment: you could use 'OnFocusChangeListener' `code` name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus == false){
     //get text...
    }
    
   }
  });

Comment: sorry i am unable to do that as my reputationn is below 15

Comment: ah ok, no problem. i'm also new here.

Answer (score 3):

**Get your `EditText` inside `onClick` block...**

This mean change the code from:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentname, container,   false);

        name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

        name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                  a=name.getText().toString().trim();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });

    return view;
}
```

To:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentname, container,   false);

        name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                  // GET EDIT TEXT HEAR:
                  EditText name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

                  a=name.getText().toString().trim();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a 3 different fragments with view pager you should:

1)Create FragmentActivity with view pager and view pager adapter.

```
public class FragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FragmentAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);     
        adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

2)Create 3 Fragments with static instance

```
public final class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{   
    public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
// your fragment xml view
        return view;
    }
}
```

3)Fill view pager adapter with it;

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

{    
    public InstallFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where i can be able to access the edittext that is inside the fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PageZero extends Fragment {
   public static  EditText name;   //change this to public static

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentname, container,
            false);
    name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

    name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Then, you can access the public static EditText name (after the view for it has been generated of course) from another fragment like this.

```
public class PageOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.componentaddress, container,
            false);

   EditText page_one_text = PageZero.name;   //you can get that variable in any fragment now, but using the class name of that fragment to access it

    return view;
}
}
```

Cheers. Please mark this as the correct answer if it helps you. You have quite a bit of answers here

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code. Working for me

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_explore, container, false);
    ed1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextTemp);
    if( ed1 == null )
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR UNABLE TO GET EDIT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_explore, container, false);
    return v;
}
```